# What is the meaning of the usage 'it ran' in square brackets?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

I was reading 'Crooked House' by Agatha Christie.
I couldnt understand the meaning of the usage which am attaching below.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could just as well be written:

> It ran:
>
> Dear Gaitskill,

With '*it ran*' meaning '*what was written in the letter*'. (Much like you'd hear "it ran something like (...)' to describe how something read or sounded in everyday speak.)

Answer (score 3):

This is an indication that the text of the letter is being quoted verbatim. The square brackets here indicate a “narrator insertion” which is not part of the text of the letter. Semantically, this is similar to writing a line of dialogue such as *“I don’t think,” **she said,** “that you quite understand me.”* The **[it ran]** is like the **she said**.